# Avoid multiple entry navigation property and many to many

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm currently working on a product management system where I have an edition page for article, here's a short definition of what my article is:

```
Article : Id, name, List<Keywords>
Keyword : Name, List<Article>
```

Meaning that when I generate the context, it create a new table `KeywordArticle`. Nothing strange here, now my problem is that I have an edition page with a grid containing the keywords linked to an article, and I can edit it to add new one, remove one, etc.

To handle this, I currentlyv have a ViewModel containing the final grid and I'm passing it to my controller.

My first idea to handle this was just to replace the context entity keywords property (entity.Keywords) by the ViewModel's one mapped to Keyword Entity. But it creates error when the liaison already exists (logic, can't create a new row with same ids).

My coworker idea to fix it is to remove everything and re-add the entity each time, but it seems to be very heavy and probably not the best idea here. Something like this:

```
foreach (var keyword in existingArticle.Keywords)
{
    existingArticle.Keywords.Remove(keyword);
}

existingArticle.Keywords = article.Keywords;
```

(where article.Keywords is my viewmodel property mapped to a collection of new Keyword Entity and existingArticle is the entity retrieved from the context)

How could I handle this? Is there any magic method or should I just loop through my list to retrieve the liaison who already exist, add them and remove the rest? Something along these lines:

```
var newKeywordsList = new List<Keyword>();

foreach (var keyword in article.Keywords)
{
    if (existingArticle.Keywords.Any(m => m.Id == keyword.Id))
    {
        newKeywordsList.Add(existingArticle.Keywords.First(m => m.Id == keyword.Id));
    }
    else
    {
        newKeywordsList.Add(keyword);
    }
}

existingArticle.Keywords = newKeywordsList;
```

To be honest, both solution seems to be bad, but I don't see how I could properly handle it. Maybe by reworking everything and only take a list of action to do on the list.

Comment: So `article` is your changed data and `existingArticle` is the current database state with loaded `Keywords`?

Comment: It is indeed, I agree, names are not very explicit

Comment: What does `Keywords` collection of the *view model* contain? List of names? And how it is *property mapped to a collection of new Keyword Entity*. Can we see that code?

Comment: I'm interesting, why you are passing list of keywords (collected from grid) to controller, while you can set different actions in controller to add, modify, delete one keyword?

Answer (score 1):

> To handle this, I currentlyv have a ViewModel containing the final grid and I'm passing it to my controller.

Bad idea. Pass ONLY ViewModel to controller without any UI classes(elements) in it.

There is NO any magic method. Do it manual.

There are 3 groups of changes.

1. New keywords. You can find them:

   ```
   var newKeywords = article.Keywords.Except(existingArticle.Keywords, new KeywordComparer()).ToList();
   ```

You must add these new entities in dbContext

2. "Possible modified" keywords. You can find them:

   ```
   var possibleModified = article.Keywords.Intersect(existingArticle.Keywords, new KeywordComparer()).ToList();
   ```

These entities need to be checked is there any update, and if yes then update in dbContext

3. Deleted keywords. You can find them:

   ```
   var deletedKeywords = existingArticle.Keywords.Except(article.Keywords, new KeywordComparer()).ToList();
   ```

These entities must be deleted from dbContext.

**UPD**

Thanks to grek40 for his advice about `Equals` method.

For right work of `Except` and `Intersect` also need comparer for `Keyword` class. Simple is:

```
    class KeywordComparer : IEqualityComparer<Keyword>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether the specified objects are equal.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// true if the specified objects are equal; otherwise, false.
        /// </returns>
        /// <param name="x">The first object of type <paramref name="T"/> to compare.</param><param name="y">The second object of type <paramref name="T"/> to compare.</param>
        public bool Equals(Keyword x, Keyword y)
        {
            return x != null && y != null && x.Id == y.Id;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a hash code for the specified object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// A hash code for the specified object.
        /// </returns>
        /// <param name="obj">The <see cref="T:System.Object"/> for which a hash code is to be returned.</param><exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException">The type of <paramref name="obj"/> is a reference type and <paramref name="obj"/> is null.</exception>
        public int GetHashCode(Keyword obj)
        {
            return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Bad idea. Pass ONLY model to controller without any UI classes(elements) in it.", ViewModel is only between View and Controller. I didn't mention Model here?

Comment: I mean ViewModel.

Comment: With an equals method that compares more than just the `Id`, you can't expect a good `possibleModified` handling. It will result in a delete & add instead.

Comment: @grek40, yes. And this is why we need comparing only by `Id`?

Comment: @HemidAbbasov oh, I'm not suggesting a particular solution, merely pointing out a problem. But yes, for the specific case of delete/add/modify handling, I would only compare Id values.

Comment: @grek40, you are right. I checked on simple lists of Keyword. Thanks.